# C# - Error listing all user accounts within Active Directory

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I am trying to list some basic details for all user-based accounts within Active Directory (with a custom icon based on if the account is enabled/disabled) using a Windows form. When running, I get this initial error and am left with the second screenshot:

[image]

[image]

For some reason, the icon resides in the 1st column instead of the 4th and I only end up with one account. My code:

```
try
{
    var domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    MessageBox.Show(domainName);

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
    {
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                ListViewItem tmpItem = null;

                DirectoryEntry child = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                switch (child.SchemaClassName)
                {
                    case "user":
                        int flag = (int)child.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
                        bool disabled = Convert.ToBoolean(flag & 0x0002);

                        if (disabled == false)
                        {
                            tmpItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                                (string)child.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                                (string)child.Properties["sn"].Value,
                                (string)child.Properties["samAccountName"].Value
                                }, (int)AdImages.User);
                            this.listView_ad.Items.Add(tmpItem);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                                (string)child.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                                (string)child.Properties["sn"].Value,
                                (string)child.Properties["samAccountName"].Value
                                }, (int)AdImages.block);
                            this.listView_ad.Items.Add(tmpItem);
                        }
                    break;

                    case "organizationalUnit":
                        break;

                    case "container":
                        break;

                    case "computer":
                        break;

                    case "group":
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + e, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

**Edit:** Removed try / catch to get full error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ComputeamPasswordManager.PasswordManager.getUsers()
   at ComputeamPasswordManager.PasswordManager.PasswordManager_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

**Edit 2:** Screenshot from Visual Studio running on a domain device...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was run Visual Studio as Admin!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this (and similar expressions):

```
(string)child.Properties["givenName"].Value
```

like this:

```
(string)child.Properties["givenName"]?.Value ?? ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, alas exactly the same outcome as my original code above.

Comment: Then you'll likely need to use the debugger to step through the code and find the exact line that throws the error. You might also (temporarily) **remove the try/catch**, as this is hiding the real location of the error.

Comment: If you run this in Visual Studio, you should also be able to see exactly which line of code throws this error. That's as important as the error message itself.

Comment: I am planning to. I'm not developing on a domain controller so need to set up VS in a test DC.

Comment: You shouldn't need to be on a special machine for this. Any domain joined machine should work, as long the user has enough permissions.

Comment: Ran VS on a test DC and attached a screenshot in my original post.

Comment: @Rawns This means `child.Properties["userAccountControl"]` results in `null`, and checking a property (ie: `Value`) on a `null` reference causes an exception. You have to be ready to deal with the `null` result there.

Comment: Issue solved. Turns out I was being really stupid and was not running Visual Studio as Admin. Running as admin returned a value for the `userAccountControl` value for every account.